# Recursive method works in java with console, but not with android

Tags: java, android, methods, recursion, static

I wrote a recursive method that gets all possible character combinations from the characters in a string. I also have a method to access it and return a list of the combos:

```
public static void uns(String word, StringBuilder s, List combos)
{
    for(char c: word.toCharArray())
    {
        s.append(c);
        if(word.length() != 1) 
            {
            uns(removeChar(word, c),s,combos);
            }
        else
        {
            combos.add(s.toString());
        }
        s.deleteCharAt(s.toString().length()-1);
    }

}

public static List getCombinations(String word)
{
    List<String> combinations = new ArrayList<String>();
    uns(word,new StringBuilder(),combinations);
    return combinations;
}

public static String removeChar(String s, char c)
{
    int index = s.indexOf(c);
    return s.substring(0,index)+s.substring(index+1);
}
```

When testing it in Java, it ran with no flaws. For some reason, when I use it in Android, the list is populated with the correct number of elements, but every element is the same. For instance, for the word "here", it returns a list filled with "eerh".

Comment: What is the definition of `removeChar()`?

Comment: @Eric Sorry, edited back in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a very weird glitch (definitely reproducible) and you may want to file a bug report on this.

However, here is a temporary workaround; instead of using `.toString()`, which appears to somehow reuse the reference (even if I do `.substring(0)` with it), so all of them get updated; if you print out the list after each iteration, you'll see what I mean.

Here is my hacky/inefficient solution. Change:

```
combos.add(s.toString());
```

... to:

```
combos.add(s + "");
```

This effectively clones the string properly into the array, so that they are not manipulated:

> `02-17 19:33:48.605: I/System.out(6502): [Combos]: [here, heer, hree, hree, here, heer, ehre, eher, erhe, ereh, eehr, eerh, rhee, rhee, rehe, reeh, rehe, reeh, ehre, eher, erhe, ereh, eehr, eerh]`

Comment: @A--C I had to try it; I couldn't believe it without seeing it with my own eyes. :)

Comment: @Eric Great, in depth answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive but i think the valueOf() method from the string class will work also. maybe try using a List instead of the StringBuilder, add characters to the list and try String.valueOf(s.get(i)); and that should convert the character to a string. i don't see why out wouldn't work in Android but you may need to modify your loop a little. hope that helps.

Comment: Nope, same glitch with `.valueOf()`. I think `String.valueOf(StringBuilder)` just returns `StringBuilder.toString()`, which is the same as the OP's code.